# Let $A$ be a set of $n(\geq 3)$ distinct elements .The number of triplets $(x,y,z)$ of the $A$ elements in which at least two coordinates is equal is?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $A$ be a set of $n(\geq 3)$ distinct elements .The number of triplets $(x,y,z)$ of the $A$ elements in which at least two coordinates is equal is?

I understand that there is an approach to get the answer by just subtracting the arrangements in which no coordinates are equal from the total possible arrangements.
$$n^3-~^nP_3$$

Can anyone please tell me an approach that could get the answer directly?

Answer (score 1):

We can choose $2$ objects from $n$ objects in $\binom{n}{2}$. We can arrange $3$ objects, $2$ of them identical, in $\frac{3!}{2!}$ ways. Now among the two objects chosen either of them can appear twice. So number of triplets with exactly two coordinates same is $2\times3\cdot\binom{n}{2}$.

There are also $n$ triplets with all three coordinates same.

Thus in total $6\cdot\binom{n}{2}+n$ triplets.

Comment: I did exactly this but this is not giving the answer, this gives 3n(n-1)/2 but the answer is n^3-nP3.

Comment: Should instead be $6\binom{n}{2}+n$, and then the two formulas agree.  Once you choose A and B, there are six possibilities: AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA, BAB, BBA

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for pointing out...totally missed it!